# HR Transaction Cube SSAS Design

Tags: transactions, ssas, cube, dimension

I’ve just hit a major road block with regards to implementing SSAS service for our HR department .

The core part would be the transaction cube and the elements are:
Employee
Transaction Date
PayCode
Position(Location)
Amount

I would image to use time, paycode and position(location) to be the slicer. But one of these "big 3" dimensions -- position, is a time-related dimensions. For instance, John was in ICU till 06/01/2014 and then moved to Emergency afterwards, so all his transactions before 06/01/2014 need to be costed to ICU and transactions costed to Emergency after 06/01/2014. Moreover, our Org Chart(hierarchy) varies over time too! For instance, Emergency was under Ambulance Service Directorate before 2013 and now it's under Acute Operations Directorate.

I just cannot think through how to handle this kind time-related dimension and hierarchy. Do I need another cube for this Employee-Date-Position relationship? How could I create the time-related hirarchy for Org Chart?

Hope you can help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply **Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2** to any time-related dimension.

You need to make corresponding changes in ETL during data loading: date dependency will be mapped here, not in SSAS.